# XDebug installation error on Centos

Tags: php, linux, netbeans, centos, xdebug

I am installing XDebug on Centos to debug NetBean PHP program.
I followed the instructions in this [link](http://programming-review.com/installing-xdebug-on-centos/). At this command, `pecl install Xdebug`, I got error as

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFilelist() on a non-object in /usr/share/pear/PEAR/Command/Install.php on line 748`.

What could be the cause of the error?y Centos version is CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 and NetBeans IDE is IDE 8.0.2. Not sure, they are required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to permission issues during install.

Please make sure that the destination folder (`php/extensions`) where the Pecl extension is trying to install extension has the write access.

So either run the command with `sudo` (which is not recommended), or correct the permission so the PHP script is able to create a new folders and files within `lib/php` folder.

---

#### OS X

This is what worked in OS X:

```
$ chmod -R ug+w /usr/local/Cellar/php*/lib/php
```

The folder to fix the permissions should be visible right above the error, e.g.

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.20/lib/php/extensions/debug-non-zts-20131226/xhprof.so'

Fatal error: Call to a member function getFilelist() on null in /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.20/lib/php/PEAR/Command/Install.php on line 747
```

so based above error you need to make sure that `/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.20/lib/php/extensions` directory exists and it's writtable.

Related:

- [GH #1039 - Can not install extension with pecl](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1039)
- [PR #50 for `pear-core` - Fix PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getFilelist() on null](https://github.com/pear/pear-core/pull/50/files)